# Getting 404 on domain served by the same server

Tags: guzzle, laravel-9

I am trying to connect to the API served on the same Ubuntu server through Guzzle and Laravel 9. Guzzle persistently throws 404 on the login API. Webserver is nginx.

I can hit it from postman from outside just fine even with no headers and never receive a 404.

Localhost deployment works fine on Windows and Apache.

**Request Wrapper**

```
protected function requestAPI(string $verb, string $endpoint, array $parameters = []): array
{
    $domain = env('API_DOMAIN');
    try {
        $client = new Client;
        $options = ['multipart' => []];
        foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
            $options['multipart'][] = [
                'name' => $key,
                'contents' => is_array($value) ? json_encode($value) : $value,
            ];
        }
        if (session()->has(SessionKeys::API_TOKEN)) {
            $options['headers'] = [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.session()->get(SessionKeys::API_TOKEN),
            ];
        }
        $json = $client->request($verb, $domain.$endpoint, $options)->getBody()->getContents();
    } catch (RequestException $exception) {
        if (Str::contains($exception->getMessage(), 'RouteNotFoundException') && request()?->route()?->getName() !== 'auth.logout') {
            die(redirect()->route('auth.logout'));
        }
    }
    return empty($json) ? [] : json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
}
```

**Login Request**

```
$response = $this->requestAPI('post', 'auth/login', [...$request->all(), 'deviceName' => 'website']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The DNS was being resolved to old mapping for some reason. The change happened a few days ago so I guess its some caching issue. Still I wasn't able to flush it or correct it so had to add a hosts mapping.

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Not the recommended course of action for sure but gets the job done when the OS refuses to cooperate.